# Trying to use react for the first time with Javascript and Node and am getting an error that I can't use an import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, importerror

I have an index.js file with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have imported react into my src folder in my app's library with `npm install --save`

Not sure why I get this issue. I also have an App.js file with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist.css.bootstrap.min.css";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component";
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercises from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercises from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUsers from "./components/create-user.component"


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <br/>
      <Route path="/" exact component = {ExercisesList} />
      <Route path="/edit/:id"  component = {ExercisesList} />
      <Route path="/create" exact component = {ExercisesList} />
      <Route path="/user" exact component = {ExercisesList} />
    </Router>
  );
}



export default App;
```

The entire exercise is based on the youtube video with a guy working through it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M&list=WL&index=17&t=0s

Comment: when do you get this error? when you run start? build? test? Can you show the error including all output related to the error

Comment: @JaromandaX I get the error when I try to run the app. I'm really new to this so not that skilled in it.

Comment: Tried running it again and it just said it can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist.css.bootstrap.min.css' in my src folder